# 2SB1241 Transistor replacement

Tags: transistors, bjt, repair, pnp, replacement

I have a Peavey PV8 USB Mixing console which doesn't turn on anymore, the problem is a burned PNP switching the +15V rail.
The Marking of the transistor is B1241 but due to the 3-SIP package im pretty sure its a 2SB1241.
I haven't found any other problems in the circuitry yet, i think only this transitor is faulty.
The 2SB1241 is a bit hard to read now, but i'm very sure it's the current gain option R with hfe 180-390.
[A datasheet can be found here.](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/173350/ROHM/2SB1241.html)
The original is discontinued and shops like Digikey, Mouser or TME don't have it in stock anymore.

I believe the high hfe, 1A collector current and 1W power dissipation should not be lower for a replacement, but i'm not sure on other parameters.
The original package is 3-SIP, but there are no big space constraints, a TO-126 or even a TO-220 would fit for example.

what i could gather from similar questions/other sources:

- [Determining Suitable Replacement Transistor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24768/determining-suitable-replacement-transistor)- "high current, high gain/high beta"
- [PNP B772 Transistor replacement [closed]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/265698/315337) - BD140 is a popular PNP, can handle even a bit more power, hfe is a bit different
- https://theknowledgeaccelerator.com/2016/04/16/jellybean-components/- lists D45H Series, a bit overkill with 10A collector current
- [EEVBlog: Common / generic / cheap / easy to find parts](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/common-generic-cheap-easy-to-find-parts/) - TIP34x (power PNP, 10A, 40-100V) also a bit overkill
- [EEVBlog: RE: Common / generic / cheap / easy to find parts](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/common-generic-cheap-easy-to-find-parts/msg286005/#msg286005) - TIP33 overkill current, too low hfe
- parts like BD240 with hfe below 100 are probably not usable

I'm not sure which other parameters should be considered, like some parameter that depends on the voltage on the base between the resistor divider and the zener maybe.

I reversed the power circuitry so you know the usecase.
The 2SB1241 switches the +15VDC comming from the external supply to the internal power rail when the switching inverter provides the -15VDC. (maybe to minimize pop-sound from the caps charging?)
Here are a simplified diagram and the complete one as screenshot from kicad:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f48cqf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: circuit]

It would be great if someone could guide me which parameters are most important for a transistor in this application/for a replacement.
It would be awesome if someone knows a fitting jellybean transistor.

I hope this question and information i allready gathered is good enough and it isn't closed.

Comment: R2/R447, is it 499 or 4990?  Is the +15V load current known? If not, calculate: how many op-amps, bias resistors, power amps, etc., what current consumption is expected of each, etc.? Or measure it by bypassing the transistor with an ammeter? Speed certainly isn't a problem, so any will do, as long as enough hFE is available. Excess current rating doesn't matter.

Comment: Oh, i have missed to correct that in the kicad schematic, it should be 499 Ohms, the SMD code is 4991.
i will meassure the current when i have time.
are parameters concerning the voltage at the base or so not so important? can i have problems if the hFE is too high?

Comment: @Thorbijoern 4991 would be 4.99 kΩ; 499 and 1 zero makes 4990.

Comment: @Hearth sorry, you're right, i checked it again. the resistor has the code 4991, so it is 4,99k.
i corrected the circuitlab schematic.